# Clebsch-Gordan Coefficients in $SU(3)$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, group-theory, representation-theory, group-representations

Where should I start in order to find the C-G coefficients for, say, the tensor product $$3\otimes 6=8\oplus 10~?$$

In general, is there a simple way to describe the calculation for a general tensor product?

Comment: [Due diligence first](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clebsch–Gordan_coefficients_for_SU(3)).

Answer (score 1):

For the specific case you have in mind, i.e. $(1,0)\otimes(2,0)$, there are several sources which Google will easily find for you.

For general results applicable to you coupling:

1. Polynominal Bases and Isoscalar Factors for SU(3)
   Journal of Mathematical Physics 7, 1105 (1966) by 
   R. T. Sharp and Hans Von Baeyer
2. Clebsch–Gordan coefficients of SU(3) in SU(2) and SO(3) bases
   Journal of Mathematical Physics 41, 6544 (2000), by 
   D. J. Rowe and C. Bahri
3. SU3 recoupling and fractional parentage coefficients
   Nuclear Physics Volume 62, Issue 1, February 1965, Pages 1-36, by  K.T. Hecht
4. There is also this resource page: http://homepages.physik.uni-muenchen.de/~vondelft/Papers/ClebschGordan/
5. The more recent SU(3) Clebsch–Gordan coefficients at large Nc,  Nuclear Physics A Volume 945, January 2016, Pages 144-152 by F.Stancu is 
   also a good place to start.

The general method is *always* the same: set up a recursion and solve.  There’s a lot of literature from the mid-60’s.  The *major* difficulty is with weight multiplicities, i.e. when n-tuples of eigenvalues of the Cartan elements occur more than once.

As a pointer and a way to start the recursion relation, note that $(1,0)\otimes (2,0)=(3,0)+(1,1)$; the highest weight state for $(3,0)$ is just the product of the highest weights in $(1,0)$ and $(2,0)$, while the highest weight for $(1,1)$ has CG given by $\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$ and $-\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}$.